# What is a term or phrase used to describe the evil reflection of a good hero: the relationship between Neo and Agent Smith?

Tags: word-request

Specifically, I am trying to describe Agent Smith from the film *The Matrix* and his relationship to Neo. Agent Smith seems to be the anti-christ to the christ-like figure Neo. They are both very powerful; neither can entirely defeat the other. Their missions and beliefs are completely opposite. Neo cares for humanity; Smith hates it. Neo is selfless; Smith is completely selfish. etc..

I have some ideas: antithesis, the polar opposite, dark shadow..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started composing an answer with several options, but stopped to grab a bite. When I came back, you have edited in some words I would have suggested to you. I was going to suggest *antithesis*, *nemesis*, and, to describe their characteristics and positions in the story, *polar opposites*.

> Agent Smith is **antithetical** to the protagonist Neo.

**Nemesis** is a good word, and could be the one you are looking for. It refers to an archenemy or a rival in a long standing rivalry.

> Lord Voldemort, Harry Potter's nemesis, dies at the end of the story.

Oh **archenemy** fits the context too.

> Agent Smith is Neo's archenemy.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. Your similar conclusion makes me feel like I am on the right track. I've settled with "the antithesis"